# How to declare a final String inside a constructor with an if-statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, constructor, final

I used to declare a final String inside a constructor. Now I want to insert an if-statement in order to declare it differently if needed.

I used to do:

```java
public Config(){
    final String path = "<path>";
    doSomething(path);
}
```

Now I'm trying

```
public Config(String mode){
    if (mode = "1") {
        final String path = "<path1>";
    } else {
        final String path = "<path2>";
    }
    doSomething(path);
}
```

Unfortunately path cannot be found now (cannot find symbol error) and I'm really lost with my research understanding this.
The following works though, I just cannot explain... I must have a deep miss conception about something here.

```
public Config(String mode){
    final String path;
    if (mode = "1") {
        path = "<path1>";
    } else {
        path = "<path2>";
    }
    doSomething(path);
}
```

Can you explain me what is going on here, what should I read about to get this.

Comment: To understand your second example you need to read up on variable scoping (which will also explain why your third example works)

Comment: What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: `if (mode = "1") {` is invalid syntax: `mode = "1"` is a `String`, not a boolean.

Comment: And `if (mode == "1")` would be wrong, too. You have to use the equals() method to compare strings.

Comment: @GhostCat it *may* be wrong :) It's *probably* wrong - just not definitely.

Comment: Why do you want to make it final, what are you trying to achieve / prevent.

Comment: @luk2303 It is a good practice to make all variables `final` by default, and require a reason to make it re-assignable.

Comment: @Thilo only when relevant. A final variable scoped in a constructor (or in any short-lived block) does not make much sense to be final. A field of a class is not the same as a local variable. Do you often see code with all local variables declared as final? I don't think so...

Comment: @Thilo it's good practice to write code where variables are effectively final, and good practice to make members final whenever possible, but the additional visual noise of making *everything* final outweighs the benefit.

Comment: @Thilo Or to say it in short: stating a universal rule to make all variables final is **not** at all a good practice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can you explain me what is going on here,

Snippet 2: `path` declared in the scope of the `if` statement. It's not accessible outside that `if`.

Snippet 3: `path` declared in the scope of the constructor. It's accessible within that constructor.

> what should I read about to get this.

The JLS, of course: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3 It's quite complicated, find the right part, read it thoughtfully and go with

```
doSomething("1".equals(mode) ? "<path1>" : "<path2>");
```

Answer (score 3):

The scope of any final variable lies within its code block. It is not visible outside this block. See this thread for why scope of final is defined this way:
[Scope of final local variable in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669993/scope-of-final-local-variable-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Thing is:

```
public Config(){
    final String path = "<path>";
    doSomething(path);
}
```

doesn't make any sense. `doSomething()` can **not** alter the String object you are passing to it anyway.

Your whole idea to use final like that is simply flawed. String objects are immutable, and that method receives a reference to such a String object. So even if you have

```
void doSomething(String whatever) {
  whatever = "in your face";
  ... 
}
```

Your `path` reference will still be the same after that call.

From that point of view, in your first example, you could (should for readability) go with `doSomething("<path>");`

Beyond that, the real answer here is: you seem to have misconceptions about proper usages of the final keyword. There is no point in declaring a variable final when it is used only once afterwards, like in your examples. Having a local variable final only prevents that this variable gets re-assigned *within* its scope. You are only *reading* the variable once, thus using *final* doesn't add anything useful to your code.

Comment: Who said that they were trying to alter the string inside `doSomething`?

Comment: the idea of declaring a variable is flawed as well, OP might have passed the literal

Comment: @JonK The example shows exactly **one** usage of that final variable.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko True, I enhanced the answer accordingly.

Comment: And? The body of `doSomething` is never shown, so how did you arrive at the conclusion that the problem is them expecting the content of the string to be changed as a side-effect?

Comment: @JonK I added another paragraph to make things more clear.

Comment: Still missing the point though - the OP actually has working code and is trying to understand why their second code snippet doesn't compile - which is due to the `path` variable being referenced after it has fallen out of scope. I agree that in the example code the use of `final` is functionally superfluous, but at the same time it doesn't actively harm the code either. Who knows, maybe their coding standards mandate that all variables are `final`.

Comment: @JonK Other answers do a nice job explaining that. I am answering to the question title that says "How to declare a final String inside a constructor with an if-statement?" ... and my answer is: in your current examples, you dont. Because it doesnt make any sense.

Comment: In fact, you can alter a String. It's a bit tricky and does not always work but it's doable on Java 8: [here is a snippet](https://ideone.com/YTe5cj). Note that having a final String does not prevent that :)

Comment: @Abrikot I know that Java has some corners for dark magic, but the newbie asking the question did start of with ` if (mode = "1")` so I did decide to not further complicate things by using reflection to get to String internal fields. And with Java 9+ and proper module support, that trick wont work anymore anyway ;-)